# how to remove the black screen when restarting app in ios

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, self

Before showing root view controller ,my app shows black screen for few seconds when restarted . i want my root view controller to come immediately .how i can achieve this ?

i set my view controller like this in app delegate :

```
test* loggedInChecker = [[test alloc]initWithNibName:@"test" bundle:nil];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loggedInChecker];


self.navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;


self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the launch image.
Create a png image that you want to be shown on app launch.
Add the image to your project by dropping in the LaunchImage under Images.xcassets

Comment: you didn't understood my question

Comment: i want similar behaviour like that in facebook app. in which app doesn’t take time to load and quickly display some thing